# Incoherent values returned by Spring Boot Pagination

Tags: spring-boot, pagination, mongotemplate

I'm trying to create a function which return a list of an Object with Page ( from spring data ).

**The problem is that the returned values "totalElements" & "total pages" are incorrect**
[image: the totals are false]

There is 10 elements, but totalElements = 110, and totalPages = 2 when the 10 elements enter easily in a page of 100 elements

PS : I am forced to use the object MongoTemplate in which there is no find function which takes a Pageable. So i'm forced to create it manually.

The code i'm using :

```
PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(orders,pageable,() -> orders.size());
```

the orders is a List of my results ( which are correct ), the page is defined like following :

```
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(pageIndex,numberOfTransactionsPerPage);
```

Thank you for everything

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have 110 elements, and you have page size 100, so 2nd page is the last page with 10 elements because other 100 elements was on 1st page.

Comment: The thing is : i have ten elements and this is the first page, it behaves like there is an index 0 page

Comment: Yes, check documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html Page index is 0 based, so if you pass page = 1 you'll get second page.

Comment: LOL! @Michał i shouldve known better